# Can't Connect to MySQL Database using Adminer and docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, adminer

I'm trying to connect to my mysql database using official `adminer` and `mysql` images from docker hub.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD= 1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE= db
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
      - 33060:33060
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
volumes:
  mysql:
```

Whenever I want to login to the MySQL using Adminer I face with the following problem:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Here is the inputs I've used trying to connect to MySQL from Adminer interface:

```html
#first try
System: MySQL
Server: localhost
Username: root
Database: db

#second try
System: MySQL
Server: mysql #container-name
Username: root
Database: db
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the default authentication plugin in compose file

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Here is the complete docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes: 
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD= 1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE= db
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
      - 33060:33060
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
volumes:
  mysql:
```

In adminer

```
System: MySQL <DB System to connect>
Server: mysql <should match the starting tag before image tag > (in your case mysql but you can change it to any name )
Username: root <username>
Password: <password>
Database: db <database name>
```

Comment: thanks, I was struggling with the server field in adminer, I did not know that we had to specify the service name from the docker-compose file rather than the container's IP address.